# Burninated [linear]ly

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

The [linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear) tag (x968) refers to linear algebra (according to its tag wiki), but there's already the [linear-algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) tag (x2967) and "linear" doesn't really imply "linear algebra" - there are plenty of questions that use the tag for other purposes; just to name a few:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126522/linearlayout-inside-another-linearlayout-issue
- [Finding a spanning tree using exactly k red edges in a graph with edges colored by red/blue in linear time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706003/finding-a-spanning-tree-using-exactly-k-red-edges-in-a-graph-with-edges-colored)
- [MIPS actual encoding scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395095/mips-actual-encoding-scheme)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150004/decoding-longest-path-bioinformatics-linear-space-algorithm-dag
- [Linear Hashing for Data Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944028/linear-hashing-for-data-storage)

Can we burninate it?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +24/-2 A1 (Saying Yes): +9/0. A2 (Saying Yes): +1/0.

Comment: You have to draw a line somewhere.

Comment: Well, you got straight to that point.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +121/-6. A1 (Saying Yes) +88/0. A2 (Saying Yes) +22/0. A3 (Saying Yes) +60/-1. A4 (saying synonymize) +4/-18. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use the tag [linear-algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra), [linear-regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-regression), [linear-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming) and [linear-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-search) for questions related to Linear Algebra, Linear Regression, Linear Programming and Linear Search respectively.
- For questions about [Linear Layout of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinear%5D%20%5Bandroid%5D%20%5Blayout%5D%20is%3Aq&mixed=0), use [android-linearlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-linearlayout) instead.

## Progress:

The [linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=linear),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinear%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinear%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinear%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinear%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196498)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=251161)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 93):

I agree. This tag does not say *what* is linear, which is what matters. If you're talking about *something* that is linear, tag it as [linear-*something*] or [*something*-linear]. Also, you cannot be an expert in 'linear'.

Let it burn.

Comment: Your comment about being an 'expert in linear' got me wondering if that is completely true.  Could someone exist that has expertise in linear 'everything'?

Comment: Linear algebra, linear motor actuator, linear flow, linear induction, linear layout, ect.   Uh, I don't think so...

Comment: True, but I have a friend who's a veritable expert in 'non-linear'... conversational non-sequiturs

Comment: @MarcelWilson I'd say the "can there be experts?" test, on the whole, more hinders than helps. In this specific case, the sheer ambiguity of [linear] is well enough to call its usefulness into question.

Comment: In SO's context, the closest would be linear programming, which definitely can be an area of expertise

Comment: @duplode I would agree. I think tag is too broad for stackoverflow.  But I try to be cautious about assumptions that something doesn't or couldn't exist just because I couldn't imagine it. I would be very curious to hear a counter argument otherwise.

Comment: @MarcelWilson oh, we are sure that linearity exists, just that we can't be sure of what exactly are the boundaries that defines it.

Answer (score 62):

I agree with the burnination request. The [linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear) tag is pretty ambiguous, and does not provide additional information than what is already present. Some of the usages of the tag, are very math specific and therefore not on-topic for the site as well. It does need an additional tag to actually determine what kind of linear it means.

Going through the list of questions, I found a few of them which could be retagged:

- Starting with [linear-algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) which the OP proposed in the question.
- There were some questions about Linear Regression, which needs to be tagged with [linear-regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-regression) instead.
- There were around [58 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinear%5D%5Bsearch%5D&mixed=0) that were tagged with [linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear)[search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/search), which need to be retagged with [linear-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-search).
- There were [a lot of questions about linear programming](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinear%5D+programming&mixed=0), which need to be tagged with [linear-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming).
- I found a few questions about [Linear Layout of Android](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blinear%5D%20%5Bandroid%5D%20%5Blayout%5D%20is%3Aq&mixed=0), which need to be tagged [android-linearlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-linearlayout) instead.

These were the ones that turned up only after a cursory glance of the questions (I went upto 3 pages). There certainly are way more targets, which can be added on while we are burninating the tag.

Comment: I see 3 answers for burn the tag and upvoted all three; however this one has the guidence.

Comment: About 100 questions tagged with [tag:linear] are also tagged with one of [tag:linear-algebra] or [tag:linear-programming] or [tag:linear-regression]. In those cases it can probably simply be removed.

Comment: 11 questions with Linear and CSS, most of them appear to be about gradients.  These should probably be tagged to [linear-gradients]  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear+css

Comment: Feel free to update the progress answer, @DanNeely

Answer (score 25):

I just came across this tag, and wondered why it existed.

The [linear-algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) tag currently has 2,448 questions tagged, and [linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear) has 818. [linear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear) doesn't have a tag wiki, only a bit under user guidance that describes linear algebra.

It needs to be burned IMO.

Answer (score -20):

How about making it a synonym of [linear-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linear-programming)? Since this is SO, that would be the primary candidate for any "linear" questions.

Comment: Read Bhargav's answer. Synonym means that the two tags always mean the same thing. In this case, they don't

Comment: Linear programming is still the main thing, other uses are meta

Comment: The tag wiki for [linear] refers to linear algebra, not linear programming. Can't just go around and change its meaning like that, even if lots of people have used the tag incorrectly.

Comment: Update the tag then? If not this meta tag will just resurface again

Comment: If it will resurface we can get rid of it while it is still small and blacklist it.

Comment: Blacklist is not necessary if most people can understand "linear" means linear programming on a programming website, which happens to be case for this tag, regardless who wrote the tag wiki (was it updated later on? how would people who used the tag earlier know or care?)

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that "most people" understand linear as linear programming? Looking at Bhargav's result, this is indeed the main category of questions, but not the overwhelming majority.

Comment: Many people misuse tags, regardless of what the tag wiki says. It's best to have tags that are fairly unambiguous based on name alone (which this tag isn't).

Comment: Linear programming has nothing to do with coding or even computers, it's a purely mathematical process. You can achieve it through code, sure, but it isn't inherently related to computers. Although it has programming in the name, the wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming doesn't even mention code or computers when describing it.

Comment: @YungGun That Wikipedia article has rather extensive sections about algorithms and solvers, though.